# Manually generating Pandas DataFrame from nested dictionary structure

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I'm trying to create a dictionary from a nested data structure (taxonomy) as follows:

```
pd.DataFrame({'genus':  ['Unknown', 'External Metal'], 
              'species':['Other Feature/Anomaly', 
                        ['Close External Metal', 'Touching Metal Object']]})
```

I get the following as output:

```
            genus                                        species
0         Unknown                          Other Feature/Anomaly
1  External Metal  [Close External Metal, Touching Metal Object]
```

Here's what I want:

```
            genus                                        species
0         Unknown                          Other Feature/Anomaly
1  External Metal                           Close External Metal 
2  External Metal                          Touching Metal Object
```

Or perhaps there is a better way of thinking about structuring these sorts of hierarchies using Pandas? I'm not opposed to having the output structured differently than I have indicated above as long as the hierarchy is properly maintained and I can easily navigate that hierarchy Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use `apply`, `pd.Series`, and `stack`:

```
df.set_index('genus').species.apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index(name='Species').drop('level_1', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
            genus                Species
0         Unknown  Other Feature/Anomaly
1  External Metal   Close External Metal
2  External Metal  Touching Metal Object
```

Comment: Great answer! Thanks.